# calculate time difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery clock that gives the time from 00:00 to 23:00.

Now I want to calculate the time difference between two times. Suppose the "in" time is 11:00, and the "out" time is 16:00.

How do I calculate the time difference in javascript?

Comment: **What have you tried?** What format is the times in? (String, Date object?) How do we retrieve the time? What format do you want the date difference in?

Comment: i have simple two text boxes which gives time in string format

Answer (score 1):

You can use Date and setHours like that:

```
var first = new Date();
first.setHours(0, 11, 0, 0);

var second = new Date();
second.setHours(0, 16, 0, 0);

alert("Diff in seconds: " + (second - first));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to use a third party JS date library such as [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from Barry, I would take a look at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

In the documentation [page](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) if you find the word "difference" you could find a guy asking for the same problem. As suggested in the comment reply you should use the TimeSpan class.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you should try [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), i think its much better than datejs.

According to momentjs example:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```